# Let $X: U(0,3 \pi)$ - Uniform on $(0,3 \pi)$ Find the distribution of Y and the expectation of Y if Y is:

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]$$Y=\begin{cases} -\sin X , x \in(0, \pi] \\- \frac{1}{2} , X \in[\pi, \frac{3 \pi}{2}]\\ \cos X, X \in [\frac{5 \pi}{2}, \frac{11 \pi}{4}] \\ \frac{3}{4}, X \in (\frac{11 \pi }{4}, 3 \pi)  \end{cases}$$

For $t\leq -1$
$:F_Y(t)=0.$
$$t \in (-1, -\frac{1}{2}):F_Y(t)= \frac{1}{3\pi}\int_{\arcsin(-t)}^{\pi -\arcsin(-t)}dt +\frac{1}{3\pi} \int_{\arcsin(-t)+\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2} -\arcsin(-t)}dt.$$

$$t \in (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}):F_Y(t)= \frac{1}{3\pi}\int_{\arcsin(-t)}^{\pi -\arcsin(-t)}dt +\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{3\pi}\int_{\arcsin(-t)+\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2} -\arcsin(-t)}dt.$$

$$t \in (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{5 \pi}{2}):F_Y(t)= \frac{1}{3\pi}\int_{\arcsin(-t)}^{\pi -\arcsin(-t)}dt +\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{3\pi} \int_{\arcsin(-t)+\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2} -\arcsin(-t)}dt+ \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

$$t \in (\frac{5 \pi}{2}, \frac{11 \pi}{4}):F_Y(t)= \frac{1}{3\pi}\int_{\arcsin(-t)}^{\pi -\arcsin(-t)}dt +\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{1}{3\pi} \int_{\arcsin(-t)+\frac{3\pi}{2}}^{\frac{5\pi}{2} -\arcsin(-t)}dt+ \frac{\pi}{4}+ \frac{1}{3\pi} \int_{\frac{5 \pi}{2}}^{t}dt.$$

It's important for me to know is my logic doing this is fine, so I typed it out more detailedly.

And for the expected value would if be $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} x f_i(x) dx   \ \ \ ; \ \ \ \ x \in (t_1, t_2)$$ whre $f_i(x)$ and $t_1, t_2$ are the functions given in at the top definition with the respected boundaries ? I realised that I made a mistake typing $dt$ when it should be $dx$..

Comment: But X is uniform, the function inside the integrals is therefore:$ \frac{1}{3 \pi}$ ??

Comment: But the density of $Y$ is not constant. And $F_Y$ should be an integral over the density of $Y$.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why you think that the density isn;t $1 \over 3 \pi $, seeing as X has uniform distribution over $(0, 3\pi)$ ? And how you think this should be done?

Comment: If $X$ is uniformly distributed , for example $cos(X)$ is not uniformly distributed. Unfortunately, I do not know how to handle this.

Comment: Would $aX + b, a,b \in R $ be uniformly distributed ?

Comment: The substitution rule for integrals should have something to do with the problem.

Comment: What's interesting we in class also saw a $AX^2 + BX+ C$ as uniformly distributed, would you disagree ?

Comment: Maybe, I am wrong, but I would it not consider to be uniformly distributed, if $X$ is.

Comment: May I ask what your background with probability is because I am sure that this is correct ?

Comment: I know what a density function is, but I have no experience with the density of a function of a random variable, like $cos(X)$, where $X$ has some concrete distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y=g(X)$ for some 1:1 function $g$ then we could use a substitution of variables (based on the chain rule of derivation):

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\Big\lvert\frac{\operatorname d g^{-1}(y)}{\operatorname d y}\Big\rvert$$

Your problem is that you don't have a nice invertable function.   The relation between X and Y is piecewise and involves several folds.   Indeed at two points $Y$ does not have a probability density but a probability mass.

We have to split the support for $Y$ into pieces, then account for these folds and massive points.

Fortunately though the density function of $X$ is a constant, $f_X(x)= \tfrac 1{3\pi}\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;3\pi)}$.

$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) \mathbf 1_{y\in [-1;-1/2)} & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}\left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d \sin^{-1}(-y)}{\operatorname d y\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\pi-\sin^{-1}(-y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\quad}\Big\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in [-1;-1/2)}
\\
F_Y(-\tfrac 1 2) & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}(\tfrac {3\pi}2-\pi)
\\
f_Y(y) \mathbf 1_{y\in (-1/2;0)} & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}\left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d \sin^{-1}(-y)}{\operatorname d y\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\pi-\sin^{-1}(-y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\quad}\Big\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in (-1/2;0)}
\\
f_Y(0) & = \Big[\tfrac 1{3\pi}\left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d \sin^{-1}(-y)}{\operatorname d y\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\pi-\sin^{-1}(-y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\quad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac {3\pi}{2}+\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac{5\pi}2-\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert\right)\Big]_{y=0}
\\
f_Y(y)\mathbf 1_{y\in(0;3/4)} & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}\left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac {3\pi}{2}+\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac{5\pi}2-\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in (0;3/4)}
\\
F_Y(\tfrac 3 4) & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}(3\pi-\tfrac{11\pi}4)
\\
f_Y(y)\mathbf 1_{y\in(3/4;1]} & = \tfrac 1{3\pi}\left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac {3\pi}{2}+\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert+\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d (\tfrac{5\pi}2-\cos^{-1}(y))}{\operatorname d y\qquad\qquad}\Big\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in (3/4;1]}
\\
f_Y(y)\mathbf 1_{y\in[5\pi/2;11\pi/4]} & = \tfrac 1{3\pi} \left(\Big\lvert\tfrac{\operatorname d y}{\operatorname d y}\Big\rvert\right)\mathbf 1_{y\in[5\pi/2;11\pi/4]}
\end{align}$$

That's the distribution of $Y$.   Evaluate the derivatives, then use these pieces to evaluate the expectation.

---

**Note:** If you weren't asked for the distribution of $Y$, I'd ignore it and calculate the expectation directly using $\mathsf E(y(X))=\int_X y(x)\;f_X(x)\operatorname d x$

We have $Y=\begin{cases} 
-\sin X         & : X \in (0; \pi] 
\\- \frac{1}{2} & : X \in (\pi; \tfrac{3 \pi}{2}]
\\ \cos X       & : X \in (\tfrac{3\pi}2; \tfrac{5\pi}{2}] 
\\ X            & : X \in (\tfrac{5 \pi}{2}; \tfrac{11 \pi}{4}] 
\\ \frac{3}{4}  & : X \in (\tfrac{11 \pi }{4}; 3 \pi]  \end{cases}$

Then the expectation we want is:

$\displaystyle\mathsf E(Y) = \tfrac 1{3\pi} \left(-\int_0^{\pi} \sin x\operatorname d x
- \int_{\pi}^{3\pi/2} \tfrac 1 2 \operatorname d x
+ \int_{3\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} \cos x \operatorname d x
+ \int_{5\pi/2}^{11\pi/4} x \operatorname d x
+ \int_{11\pi/4}^{3\pi} \tfrac 3 4\operatorname d x
 \right)$

Comment: Now, is $aX^2+bX+c$ uniformly distributed, if $X$ is ? The OP claims this in a comment.

Comment: @Peter Clearly not.  Just sketch a graph of any parabola and observe that the image will be denser closer to the apex .  A small constant increase in $X$ at different points on the support does not produce the same sized change in $aX^2+bX+c$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that, but I got unsure ...